# not able to get one polymer property value into another polymer property which is returning value as a function

Tags: ajax, polymer

I have below piece of code which i am using to call http request using iron ajax with polymer so passing the value of body and last-response using polymer properties.as we can see here we have requestBody polymer property in this we are returning no of values in requestBody all values are hardcodes like start and end and name under tag.

Now my problem is  i want to get uri value in name instead of passing of hardcode value in name i want to get uri value dynamically under the name parameter whenever uri value change .

```
   <iron-ajax
      id="Request"
      method="POST"
      content-type="application/json"
      auto
      url="/api/series/v1/points"
      last-response="{{Data123}}"
      body="{{requestBody}}">
    </iron-ajax>

 Polymer({
      is: 'test-view',

      behaviors: [GlobalsBehaviour],

      properties: {

  uri: {
          type: String,
          observer: '_uriChanged'
        },

 requestBody:{
          type: Object,
          value: function() {
            return {
              "start": 11111,
               "end": 123333,
              "tags": [
                {
                "name" : "/asset/India/rotor",
                }
              ]
            };
          }
        }, 

 Data123:{
            type: Object,
            observer: '_formateData'
        },

  observers: [
      '_uriChanged(globals.uri)'
    ],
```

i have tried like this `"name" : this.uri`,and `"name" : uri`, but not able to get value 
Note : uri is  coming from another polymer component and in some case its coming from global set variable.

Please let me know how can i get uri value in name attribute which is in requestBody property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove auto from iron-ajax tag, then change _uriChanged function as follows

```
_uriChanged: function(uri) {
  this.set('requestBody.tags.0.name', uri);
  this.$.Request.generateRequest();
}
```

Comment: one thing i observed its working fine i am getting the response data now problem is for only first time its hitting two request as i checked in network tab in browser where in first request we are not getting name attribute in request payload or we can say we are getting null in name attribute as i used in  "name" : this.assetUri  in requestBody property. so its giving 400 bad request after that its working fine for all request and hitting once only in first request its hitting twice . any suggestion what can i do to resolve this issue ??

Comment: did you removed auto in iron-ajax?

Comment: check if _uriChanged called twice. if yes move the request call to ready method.

Comment: Regarding above code can any one please help me out with this 

if i want to set dynamically "end" attribute value (which is the return value of  (requestBody) based on the uri.
i tried using  this.set('requestBody.end', "1113444") in _uriChanged callback . but it didnt work